# Regarding the use of intent in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I knew what is an intent in android. But i have a concern regarding the use of intent. I searched for the answer,
but didnt get any satisfiable answers. So here is my questions related to intents

1. How the android system recognizes the intent call. ie, when we are using implicit intent how the android system recognizes 
   this intent
2. if we have two or more activities and more than three intents, how the android Os or app recoginizing each intent call

Any help is appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intent Resolver will find the suitable component for which intent is actually looking for.
In implicit intent, if you specify the intent action, intent resolver will search in the application components(activity, service, reciever) and it will find the component which perform the specified intent action.  If there are more activities perform the same action then popup dialog will appear. There you can choose the activity which you want.

Comment: I got the answer. Than you Raghu Nagaraju...

Comment: For others, No need for further voting down and answers for this question